Flask blueprint not working when registering a blueprint in another file, I get a 404
I have a main file with the following
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from blueprints.server_config import server_config
app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(server_config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)


I then have another file called blueprints/server_config.py containing the following code:
from flask import Flask, render_template,  request
from flask import Blueprint

server_config = Blueprint('server_config', __name__)


@server_config.route('/server_config', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def server():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


def register(a, b):
    return "Not required"


When I run the code going to the URL localhost:5001/server_config gives me a 404.
What am I missing?
I tried the above code but I keep getting a 404. I also inspected app.url_map.iter_rules() and the only url present is:
'/static/path:filename'
Just in case it matters, I'm using flask 3.0.3

i recreated your project with the 2 files you provided and /server_config is working.

I'm wondering if there is something with my version of Flask. Could you share with me your versions. Here is what I'm using:

Python 3.8.19
Flask==3.0.3
Flask-RESTful==0.3.10
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1


I just tried version 2.3.3 of Flask and got the same issue. Any thoughts on what could be causing a difference in your results from mine?
Here is the Flask web server output when I try to access '/server_config'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2024 18:18:51] "GET /server_config HTTP/1.1" 404

I got everything working. I'm still not sure why the above example did not work for me. to fix things I just refactored my project following the official tutorial for Flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/
